# UCK Customize Kit Run Console ERROR status 8

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iso-image

I want to customize my Ubuntu image with same extra applications and same will be removed So I need to run console in `uck-gui`. But at this point I get stuck because of `while true;do ... ;done` loop.

```
  function run_console()
{
    echo "Starting console application..."
    CONSOLE_APP=`which konsole`
    CONSOLE_APP_OPTIONS=(--caption "UCK customization console" -e /bin/bash)
    if [ "$CONSOLE_APP" = "" ]; then
            CONSOLE_APP=`which gnome-terminal`
######## I removed -t option because it is no longer avaible.
        CONSOLE_APP_OPTIONS=(-e /bin/bash)
    fi
    if [ "$CONSOLE_APP" = "" ]; then
        CONSOLE_APP=`which xfce4-terminal`
        CONSOLE_APP_OPTIONS=(-T "UCK customization console" -e /bin/bash)
    fi
    if [ "$CONSOLE_APP" = "" ]; then
        CONSOLE_APP=`which lxterminal`
        CONSOLE_APP_OPTIONS=(-t "UCK customization console" -e /bin/bash)
    fi
    if [ "$CONSOLE_APP" = "" ]; then
        CONSOLE_APP=`which xterm`
        CONSOLE_APP_OPTIONS=(-title "UCK customization console" -e /bin/bash)
    fi

    if [ "$CONSOLE_APP" = "" ]; then
        dialog_msgbox "Failure" "Unable to find any console application"
    else
        eval `dbus-launch --sh-syntax --exit-with-session 2>/dev/null`
        $CONSOLE_APP "${CONSOLE_APP_OPTIONS[@]}"
        RESULT=$?
    fi
}
```

When I choice `RUN_CONSOLE` it runs this function but When I do this manually with gnome-terminal or konsole(which is installed after failure.). I get this output:

```
makgun@makgun02:~$ CONSOLE_APP=`which konsole`
makgun@makgun02:~$ CONSOLE_APP_OPTIONS=(--caption "UCK customization console" -e /bin/bash)
makgun@makgun02:~$ $CONSOLE_APP "${CONSOLE_APP_OPTIONS[@]}"
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
Could not find drkonqi at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/drkonqi
makgun@makgun02:~$ The font for use in the terminal has not been matched exactly. Perhaps it has not been found properly.
The font for use in the terminal has not been matched exactly. Perhaps it has not been found properly.
uint DBusMenuExporterDBus::GetLayout(int, int, const QStringList&, DBusMenuLayoutItem&): Condition failed: menu
```

AND it opened a new konsole screen but when I run this script I get this error and I get stuck on while loop.(*THE last prompt generated by terminal .So this command exitted but it will run again immedately. I couldnt understand what is done on background*.)
The Error Message is that:

```
CHOICE='Run console application'
Starting console application...
Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.gnome.Terminal exited with status 8
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
/tmp/customization-scripts/customize: line 143: [: Continue: binary operator expected
CHOICE='Continue building'
Done
```

When I continue anyway, IT FINISHED CREATION SUCCESFULLY. I just removed all language except english.It just decreased size of ISO about 200MB.
**What the problem can be?**

Gnome-terminal Version:

```
makgun@makgun02:~$ gnome-terminal --version
GNOME Terminal 3.16.2
```

KONSOLE VERSION:

```
makgun@makgun02:~$ konsole -v
Qt: 5.4.2
KDE Frameworks: 5.15.0
Konsole: 15.08.0
```

Comment: I have this problem as well.

Comment: Still not answered. :(

Comment: It looks like, even though a package is available for the latest Ubuntu version, it is not actually maintained anymore and is broken. I've decided to follow https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization instead and write some bash scripts to help perform some of the steps such as loop-mounting the image and then rsyncing the files to a working directory.

Comment: If you write a script , please share it with me. I don't have enough time to try it or doing it with manual steps. But after a month, i think I have time. Thanks.